# Given $\operatorname E(x,2)=a\implies x=f(a)$, what is the solution for $\operatorname E(x,2)=ia$ with elliptic integral of the second kind?

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions, transformation, inverse-function, elliptic-integrals

$\DeclareMathOperator\I I \DeclareMathOperator\E E \DeclareMathOperator\F F \def\L{\text L}$Some geometric problems require inverting [elliptic E](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html), especially $\E(x,2)$. One symbolic way to do so is using [inverse beta regularized $\I^{-1}_x(a,b)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html), $0\le x\le 1$, and the [second lemniscate constant $\L_2$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html):

$$\E(x,2)=a\implies x=\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\I^{-1}_\frac a{\L_2}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)}\right)$$

However, many problems require solving $\E(x,2)=ia,a\in\Bbb R$ for which the above formula fails. It turns out using a [negative parameter transform](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326579989_New_variable_transformation_of_elliptic_integrals) that:

$$\E(x,2)=\L_2+ia\implies x=\frac\pi2-\frac12\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\I^{-1}_\frac a{\L_2}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)}\right)$$

However, this is not the formula we want. It is possible to solve similar equations with [elliptic F](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html). Applying a [complementary transform](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7) gives:

$$\E(x,-1)-\F(x,-1)=\L_2-\E\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt2}\right),2\right)$$

gives:

$$\E(x,-1)-\F(x,-1)=a\implies x=\\\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{\I^{-1}_\frac a{\L_2}\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\right)\\ \E(x,-1)-\F(x,-1)=ia\implies x=\\i\sinh^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{\I^{-1}_\frac a{\L_2}\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\right)$$

If possible, what is the corresponding formula solving $\E(x,2)=i a$?